# Background (canvas) color disappears when rendering multi-mesh object in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm currently learning WebGL, and I try to render an object with 2 separate meshes (a cube and a pyramid). To represent the object in WebGL, I use a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
var V = [[-1, -1, -1,          // Vertices
           1, -1,  1,
           ...],               // Cube
         [-1, -1,  1,
           1, -1,  1,
           ...]                // Pyramid
        ];
var VBuffer = new Array();     // Vertex buffer for createBuffer()

var F = [[1, 5, 6,  1, 6, 2,   // Triangle facets
          2, 6, 7,  2, 7, 3,
          ...],                // Cube
         [0, 1, 4,  1, 2, 4,
          ...]                 // Pyramid
        ];

var NVF = [18, 12];            // Total no. of vertices in F
```

Then for the initialization of buffer in WebGL, I have:

```
function initBuffers(idx) {
  VBuffer[idx] = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VBuffer[idx]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(V[idx]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  ...
}
```

The facets of the triangles are initialized in the same way. To render the objects:

```
function drawScene(idx) {
  ...
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VBuffer[idx]);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute[idx], 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  ...
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, NVF[idx], gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  ...
}
```

These routines are called in the HTML page as follows:

```
function setInt(f, i, interval) {                    // To animate the object
  setInterval(function() { f(i); }, interval);
}

function start() {
  ...
  if (gl) {
    gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
      initShaders(i);
      initBuffers(i);
    }

    orthoMatrix = makeOrtho(-4, 4, -3, 3, 0.1, 100.0);
    mvMatrix = Matrix.I(4);
    mvTranslate([0.0, 0.0, -7.0]);

    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
      setInt(drawScene, i, 15);
    }
  }
}
```

The rendering and animation work, but the background (canvas) color is white, not as specified in gl.clearColor(). Any idea/suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution already: gl.clearColor() must be put inside drawScene(), so that it's always called when drawScene() is refreshed by setInt(drawScene, i, 15). There's another suggestion to use requestAnimFrame() rather than setInterval(), but I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- the white is the default color of the canvas and it is still there because webGL context is not properly initialized. Check console, if there are some errors with init, than you found your porblem, if that's not the case then it's second option
- the white is drawn on canvas with no errors and that might happen if your shaders output the white fragments and you put too big objects, so you ended up looking at one side of the pyramid/cube and everything else is being blocked from the view because of that one side.

Looking forward to feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today. My solution is put gl.clearColor and also gl.clear just before the calling to gl.drawElements.

In my code, gl.drawElements is called in an image onload event, so i need to do so to keep the canvas background color right.